# How to get non repeated element in array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
   (
      "userServiceIds": "1,2,3",
      "enggServiceIds": "4,5,6,2,1",
   )
```

As In these array we need Only `enggServiceIds` only where It must not be repeated in `userServiceIds`

As my required result is : - `4,5,6` only

the code must be run in PHP

I have tried this code

```
$input = array("$data[userServiceIds]" , "$data[enggServiceIds]");
            $result = implode(',',$input);
            $str = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $result)));
```

but the result is :- `1,2,3,4,5,6`

As my required result is : - `4,5,6` only

Comment: And where is the code that you have tried ?

Comment: I don't think it's array. It's json `{}`?

Comment: its first its json then its converting to array

Comment: I think you want [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) rather than simply `array_unique()`

Comment: not working array_diff()

Comment: "not working" is not a valid description of a problem.... in what way is it not working? Does it return incorrect values? does it result in an error message? does it result in your house being over-run by angry gerbils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the input is JSON, convert it to array first. Then using [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$json = '{
  "userServiceIds": "1,2,3",
  "enggServiceIds": "4,5,6,2,1"
}';

$aData = json_decode($json, true);

$aResult = array_diff(explode(',',$aData['enggServiceIds']), explode(',',$aData['userServiceIds']));

print_r($aResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

read up on [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$userServiceIds = [1,2,3];
$enggServiceIds = [4,5,6,2,1];

var_dump(array_diff($enggServiceIds, $userServiceIds));
```

returns:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(4)
  [1]=>
  int(5)
  [2]=>
  int(6)
}
```

[live preview](https://3v4l.org/kYKl6)

Answer (score 1):

solution:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array(3,4,5,6);
$resultarray = array();
$resultarray = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

result:

```
Array ( [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 )
```